# Good answers to closed questions

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, answers

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71270/why-is-wont-allowed/71271#comment137949_71271) was closed today because it was a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of). Today's question, however, had a really good answer — by one Jon Purdy — which I believe actually adds to the answers given to the earlier question. Since today's question has been closed, readers will be less likely to encounter this good answer that was posted today.

So my question is, what's to be done when there is a good answer to a question that is subsequently closed? Is there a way to migrate that answer over to the prior question? Sure, you'll say that someone posting an answer should check first to see if the question is a duplicate. Be that as it may, there's a good answer out that that I think deserves a wider audience than it's going to get. There are likely others, too.

I looked through the questions here to see if there was anything about this issue, and I couldn't find anything. But I *am* sorry if *this* question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the most brilliant timing I have ever seen. As it happens, we can merge duplicate questions, and I saw a flag requesting this just before seeing this Meta post. So the questions have been merged and this specific case has been addressed.

As for the more general case, we probably should be merging more duplicate questions that have answers. If you see some, please flag them so they can be looked at by a mod. We can also maybe do a community project where we go through closed-as-duplicate questions with answers and see if they should be merged, but I can't coordinate a project of that magnitude right now, so it'll have to wait until later in the summer unless someone else wants to take it up.

Comment: Good timing indeed. And a great (future) project, too.